# How do I search issues in JIRA, which have been resolved by a particular user/developer?

Tags: jira, jql

How do I search for issues which have a comment from a particular user/users??

Thanks
Varun

Answer (score 1):

Just install the free [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) plugin, then search for something like this with JQL:

```
issueFunction in commented("after -52w by scott")
```

This will show you all issues that were commented upon by user "scott" within the last 52 weeks.

More syntax help [here](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Scripted+JQL+Functions#ScriptedJQLFunctions-commented%28commentquery%29).

If you also need to query based on who resolved a particular issue (which is what the summary suggests, which is somewhat different from the question posed in the body above), then you want to use something like "status was resolved by scott" instead.

Comment: Just grep the XML backup ;-) Seriously, Script Runner is the way to go.

Comment: My other suggestion was going to be to perform an XSLT transformation on the XML backup, pipe it through nroff, and then just type "man scott" to get the individually-generated man page showing issues I had commented on. But that seemed like the long way around the barn. :-)

Comment: If you attach a logic analyzer to the RAM you can tell it to break on patterns such as "scott"!